# Visual Studio add Azure DevOps Server (on prem) as Symbol Server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I try to add a **Azure DevOps Server** (on prem) as Symbol Server. Unfortunately I am not able to add the Server with the `Connect to Azure DevOps Symbol Server` dialog.

[image]

After a click on **Add** I could add my Server Url. But what ever I input, the Dialog is not able to find the Server.

The url pattern is: https://azure-server.de/

What is wrong? Connecting with the **Team Explorer** instead is no problem.

---

Meta:

```
Artifacts: Activated
Version: 17.153.29207.5 (AzureDevOps2019.Update1)
Proxy: Yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Symbol Server is not embedded in on-premises installations of Azure DevOps. It is only available in Azure DevOps Services, hence the absence of possibilities to connect to an on-premises server. You can check it in the [Features Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline): search for **symbol server** and you'll see that the **server** column indicates **N/A**.

You can read the [same here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops-2019); and, [in this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/connect-announcements/), the author says:

> We plan to bring Symbol Server support to our on-prem TFS product, as
> soon as we can.

But apparently that never happened...

I would advise you to use the File Share option (although not an ideal situation) when publishing & reading Symbols.